# reading multiple bitmaps from memorystream

Tags: delphi

I need some help about Delphi bitmaps and memory stream.
I'm just fiddling Debenu PDF library, and ought to render pdf pages to BMP, then later read them back into Image component:

```
var  
    Image1: TImage;
    Image2: TImage;   
    PDF: TDebenuPDFLibrary;
    MS: TMemoryStream;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        PDF.LoadFromFile('D:/something.pdf','');
        MS:=TMemoryStream.Create;
        PDF.RenderPageToStream(72,1,0,MS);
        MS.Position:= 0; 
        Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
        Image1.Repaint;
        MS.Free;
    end;
```

It works, so far so good!
But when I try to load more than one images, I'll get runtime message:

```
"Stream read error"
```

The code I'm trying:

```
var 
    Image1: TImage;
    Image2: TImage;   
    PDF: TDebenuPDFLibrary; //To render PDF to bitmaps
    MS: TMemoryStream;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        PDF.LoadFromFile('D:/something.pdf','');
        MS:=TMemoryStream.Create;
        PDF.RenderPageToStream(72,1,0,MS); //First page
        PDF.RenderPageToStream(72,2,0,MS); //Second page
        MS.Position:= 0; 
        Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
        Image1.Repaint;
        Image2.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
        Image2.Repaint;
        MS.Free;
    end;
```

Any help?

Comment: Oh, it's just a mispelling.

Comment: Please fix that with an edit to the question. Are you sure that `RenderPageToStream` doesn't seek to the beginning of the stream? Why don't you put each image in a separate stream?

Comment: Ah so! And how can I write several bitmaps to a stream? If I can write only one into a stream, it doesn't different from a variable at all.

Comment: I don't really understand that comment.

Comment: I mean a stream is like a file, isn't is? I'd like store in it two (or more) bitmaps, then read them back one by one. (The PDF library can write many rendered pages to a stream with its RenderDocumentToStream method). But how can I 'step' along stream, and read several bitmaps?

Comment: It is similar to a file yes. My guess is that `RenderPageToStream` overwrites what was there before. You can check that easily enough. I cannot.

Comment: FWIW, the call to `Repaint` is surely not needed. The control will update itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load multiple images from a single source stream, you are best off delimiting the images within the stream and then using separate streams for each load.  This makes it very clear within the stream data where one image ends and the next image begins.  For example:

```
procedure RenderPDFToStream(PDF: TDebenuPDFLibrary; Page: Integer; Stream: TStream);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  Size: Integer;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    PDF.RenderPageToStream(72, Page, 0, MS);
    Size := MS.Size;
    Stream.WriteBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
    if Size > 0 then
      Stream.CopyFrom(MS, Size);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure LoadBitmapFromStream(Stream: TStream; Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  Size: Integer;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
    if Size > 0 then
      MS.CopyFrom(Stream, Size);
    MS.Position := 0;
    Bitmap.LoadFromStream(MS);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
var 
  Image1: TImage;
  Image2: TImage;   
  PDF: TDebenuPDFLibrary; //To render PDF to bitmaps

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  PDF.LoadFromFile('D:/something.pdf','');
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    RenderPDFToStream(PDF, 1, MS);
    RenderPDFToStream(PDF, 2, MS);
    MS.Position := 0; 
    LoadBitmapFromStream(MS, Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
    LoadBitmapFromStream(MS, Image2.Picture.Bitmap);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found out a similar solution, but this is more clear!

Comment: That's not my experience. It was my initial belief that this was so. But my tests indicate that what you state in the answer is not true. Calling LoadFromStream in my tests did not advance Position to the end of the stream. If you look at my answers history you'll see I said exactly the same as you do here but retracted it when I found that it is not so.

Comment: I've done another experiment and can confirm that what you state in your text is incorrect. I would be pleased if you could correct this misleading statement. Especially since your answer has been accepted. The reason that @user accepted your answer, I guess, is that your code does solve the problem. But not for the reason that you state. Note that your code to write makes sure that `RenderPageToStream` writes to an empty stream, and then copies to the true destination. The fact that this seems to solve the problem is more evidence that the hypothesis in my answer is accurate.

Comment: I don't care at all which answer is accepted. As always, all I care about is that what we write here, and what is blessed by acceptance and upvotes, is accurate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If you look at the implementation of `TBitmap.LoadFromStream()` for yourself, you would see that it calls `TBitmap.ReadStream()` setting its `Size` parameter to the *entire* unread portion of the stream from current `Position` onwards. If the stream's `Position` is **not** 0, `ReadStream()` copies the **entire** unread data from current `Position` to end-of-stream into a temp `TMemoryStream` before then parsing the bitmap data from it.  So only when reading a stream from the very beginning does `ReadStream()` only read the bitmap data and nothing more beyond it.

Comment: I was able to concatentate two bitmaps and then read them with two consecutive calls to `LoadFromStream`. Ok and I can do it for three bitmaps. What you state in this answer is just wrong. Do you think I have no idea what I'm talking about?

Comment: @DavidHerrernan: I just double-checked the VCL source code for a third time, and now notice that the code I was looking at is wrapped inside an `{$IFDEF CLR}` block, so the flaw only occurs on DotNet. However, that does not negate the *design* that my answer proposes. It is still a good design, and is the same way that the DFM streaming system itself implements binary data within a DFM stream.

Comment: Thank you for accepting that I have been correct here. I certainly agree that the code in your answer is a sound way to solve the problem. There are many ways to make a container format, you have demonstrated one of them. I have only ever been making the point that the text in your answer is incorrect and misleading. I also believe that the problem is as identified in my answer. I believe that you should correct the factual errors in your answer. You might also care to explain why the code in the question fails.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for the problem you occur is that `RenderPageToStream` seeks to the beginning of the stream before writing. It is possible to concatenate bitmaps into a stream and read them with consecutive calls to `TBitmap.LoadFromStream`, it follows that the problem must lie in the code that writes to the stream. And thus `RenderPageToStream` is the likely culprit.

If this is so, and it should be easy enough to add some diagnostics to your program to detect this, then you should deal with the issue by placing each image in a separate stream. Or, re-use the same stream, but do not attempt to put more than a single image into it at once. Or use some form of compound storage to place multiple images in a single stream, as demonstrated by Remy's answer.